# Free UI tools for Cappuccino?

Tags: user-interface, cappuccino, objective-j

I'm looking for free tools to design the UI for my web app.
I'm pretty new to this field, so please point me to acceptable solutions.
Basically, I need to fill a "screen" with some controls, that's it.
Thanks.

**EDIT:** Well, as soon as nobody answers, maybe somebody can help me with this problem for some framework other than Cappuccino?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Mac, you can use Apple's UI design tool Interface Builder and then convert the result to Cappuccino using the nib2cib utility. But if you're pretty new, this might not be the solution you need since it does require decent understanding of the code. Still, it is free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well, I'm pretty new to the Cappuccino, but I'm well experienced with other (not web-oriented) technologies. So this might me a good solution...

Comment: Here's the link: http://wiki.github.com/280north/cappuccino/nib2cib

Answer (score 3):

[gomockingbird](http://gomockingbird.com) is a GREAT wireframing tool.

Also check out Powerpoint or Keynote, as they are great for this too!

Answer (score 2):

Go here [The Dev Show](http://5by5.tv/devshow/7) they did a whole episode on wireframing and tools. If you don't want to listen to the podcast look at the show notes as lots of pointer.

You can now use Google Docs for free to do this and there are a lot of templates for this for UI etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) is a great wireframe tool.